# Equivalence of two descriptions of differentials of Koszul complex

Tags: rt.representation-theory, linear-algebra, homological-algebra

My question comes from learning the paper [BGS96] Koszul duality patterns in representation theory by Beilinson, Ginzburg and Soergel, published in 1996.

Let $A=T_{A_0}A_1/\langle R\rangle$ be a quadratic ring with $A_0$ semisimple and $A_1$ finitely generated over $A_0$ as left $A_0$-module, where $R$ is the relations of degree 2. Then in [BGS96], they define the Koszul complex of $A$ as

$$...\rightarrow A\otimes_{A_0}{^{\ast}}(A_{i+1}^{!})\rightarrow A\otimes_{A_0}{^{\ast}}(A^{!}_{i})\rightarrow...$$

Here comes the question, what is the differential of this complex? The authors give two descriptions of these differential maps, but I am confused why they are equivalent. (Maybe I miss some key point when checking the equivalence.)

The **Frist** one is using the idea of "double dual" and deduce that an isomorphism  of left $A_0$-module
$${^{\ast}}(A^{!}_{i})\simeq\bigcap_{j=0}^{i-2}A_1^{\otimes_{A_0}j}\otimes_{A_0}R\otimes_{A_0}A_1^{\otimes_{A_0}(i-j-2)}\subset A_1^{\otimes_{A_0}i}.$$

As stated in [BGS96] 2.6, now the differentials can be induced by
$$A\otimes_{A_0}A_1^{\otimes_{A_0}i}\rightarrow A\otimes_{A_0}A_1^{\otimes_{A_0}(i-1)}$$
$$a\otimes x_1\otimes...\otimes x_i\mapsto ax_1\otimes x_2...\otimes x_i $$.

The **Second** one using the following isomorphism
$$A\otimes_{A_0}{^{\ast}}(A_{i}^{!})\simeq {\rm{Hom}}_{\rm{Mod}-A_0}(A^{!}_i,A),$$
$$a\otimes \phi\mapsto (v\mapsto a\phi(v)).$$ Then given $f:A_{i+1}^{!}\rightarrow A$, the composition $$A^{!}_i\rightarrow A^{!}_i\otimes_{A_0}A_0\rightarrow A^{!}_i\otimes_{A_0}A_1^{\ast}\otimes_{A_0}A_1\rightarrow A_{i+1}^{!}\otimes_{A_0}A_1\rightarrow A\otimes_{A_0}A_1\rightarrow A$$
gives a homomorphism of left $A$-module homomorphism. Then they use this to give another description of differential maps.

**Question again** How to get the equivalence of these two descriptions of differential maps?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: What exactly worries you though? Let's think about the case $A_0$ being the ground field for a second. Under various finite dimensionality assumptions necessary for all this to make sense, the graded dual of an algebra is a coalgebra (and that is what is implicit in the first recipe when you split out the first tensor factor). All the information about duality can be 'packaged' by writing $Id_{A_1}\in End(A_1)\cong A_1^*\otimes A_1$ via a basis and a dual basis, which is precisely what is being used in the second recipe.

Comment: @Vladimir Dotsenko Thank you for your comments! Now I see what happens and this question is easy. In fact, I made a mistake when giving a correspondence between elements in $A_1^{\otimes i}$ and $^{\ast}({A_1^{\ast}}^{\otimes i})$.